# The <img> is not fitting to screen (100%)

Tags: html, css

When I put 100% as the width for the image, it does not fully fit to screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/we238pLx/

```
   <html><meta name='viewport' content='width=400, user-scalable=no'> <title>Community Feed </title><body bgcolor='#2E9AFE'><div class='entire'><center><font face='HelveticaNeue-Light' font size='5'><img src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/pro_pics/default.jpg class='pro_pic'><br>Hilardy</center><img class='upload' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/uploads/test.gif
 width='100%' ><center>Modern Day Creepers</center><br><center><a style='text-decoration:none' href=http://bithumor.co/like.php?type=post&id=33><img src='http://bithumor.co/likebutton.png' width='50' height='50'><br></a><br></center></div><br><div class='entire'><center><font face='HelveticaNeue-Light' font size='5'><img src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/pro_pics/59iJl41V_400x400.jpeg     class='pro_pic'><br>BitHumorKing</center><img class='upload' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/uploads/image.jpg width='100%' ><center>Test :)</center><br><center><a style='text-decoration:none' href=http://bithumor.co/like.php?type=post&id=18><img src='http://bithumor.co/likebutton.png' width='50' height='50'><br></a><br></center></div><br><div class='entire'><center><font face='HelveticaNeue-Light' font size='5'><img src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/pro_pics/default.jpg class='pro_pic'><br>Hilardy</center><img class='upload' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/uploads/schoolsucks.jpg width='100%' ><center>School is Hell</center><br><center><a style='text-decoration:none' href=http://bithumor.co/like.php?type=post&id=17><img src='http://bithumor.co/likebutton.png' width='50' height='50'><br></a><br></center></div><br><div class='entire'><center><font face='HelveticaNeue-Light' font size='5'><img src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/pro_pics/default.jpg class='pro_pic'><br>Test</center><img class='upload' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/uploads/KjXsUgfV.jpg width='100%' ><center>Test</center><br><center><a style='text-decoration:none' href=http://bithumor.co/like.php?type=post&id=13><img src='http://bithumor.co/likebutton.png' width='50' height='50'><br></a><br></center></div><br><div class='entire'><center><font face='HelveticaNeue-Light' font size='5'><img src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/pro_pics/default.jpg class='pro_pic'><br>Test</center><img class='upload' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/uploads/IntroducingBitHumor-1-2.png width='100%' ><center>Test</center><br><center><a style='text-decoration:none' href=http://bithumor.co/like.php?type=post&id=12><img src='http://bithumor.co/likebutton.png' width='50' height='50'><br></a><br></center></div><br><div class='entire'><center><font face='HelveticaNeue-Light' font size='5'><img src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/pro_pics/default.jpg class='pro_pic'><br>Test</center><img class='upload' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/uploads/bh_info-1.jpg width='100%' ><center>Test</center><br><center><a style='text-decoration:none' href=http://bithumor.co/like.php?type=post&id=9><img src='http://bithumor.co/likebutton.png' width='50' height='50'><br></a><br></center></div><br><div class='entire'><center><font face='HelveticaNeue-Light' font size='5'><img src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/pro_pics/default.jpg class='pro_pic'><br>Test</center><img class='upload' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/uploads/introducingbithumor.png width='100%' ><center>Test :)</center><br><center><a style='text-decoration:none' href=http://bithumor.co/like.php?type=post&id=8><img src='http://bithumor.co/likebutton.png' width='50' height='50'><br></a><br></center></div><br><style>
.entire {
background-color:#2E9AFE;
width: 100%;
}
.pro_pic {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    }
</style>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm a little puzzled.  When I try your fiddle, the image appears to be scaling to 100% horizontally using Chrome 41.  Is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: its working here.. albeit a questionable gif on so many levels! ;]

Comment: Firefox latest also seems to be scaling 100%.

Can you format your fiddle html so it is clear which div has which class, because now it is not really transparent what is happening

Comment: @BitHumorDeveloper You dont seem to be having a good track of accepting answers. Please find the answer below, upvote and mark it as accepted if you find it good enough or else please comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the default `margin` and `padding` that browsers add by default:

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Add this to the top of your other CSS.

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/we238pLx/1/)